# Issues changing the states components from child component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

The state of the must change. The logic is this: the handleClick is passed from a a stateful components to a child components as a parameter, and that function is passed again as a parameter and called in the child's component child's component.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      total: null,
      next: null,
      operation: null,
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(buttonName) {
    const data = calculate(this.state, buttonName);
    const  { next, total, operation} = data;

    this.setState(state => ({
      next: next,
      total: total,
      operation: operation,
    }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={calcStyle}>
        <Display result={this.state.next} />
        <ButtonPanel clickHandler={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

here is the calculate module:

```
const calculate = (data, buttonName) => {
  const operators = ['+', '-', 'X', '÷', '%'];
  const digits = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.'];
  let { total, next, operation } = data;
  const library = {
    '+/-': () => {
      next *= -1;
    },
    AC: () => {
      total = null;
      next = null;
      operation = null;
    },
    '=': () => {
      return operate(total, next, operation);
    }
  };
  const isOperation = buttonName => operators.includes(buttonName);
  const isDigit = buttonName => digits.includes(buttonName);

  if (isOperation(buttonName)) {
    total = next;
    next = null;
    operation = buttonName;
  } else if ((isDigit(buttonName) && total && operation)) {
    next = (next == null ? '' : next) + buttonName;
  } else if (isDigit(buttonName)) {
    next = (next == null ? '' : next) + buttonName;
  } else {
    library[buttonName]();
  }
  return data;
};
```

handleClick is passed as a parameter called clickHandler in the ButtonPanel, then:

```
const ButtonPanel = (props) => {
  const { clickHandler } = props;
  return (
  <div style={panelStyle}>
    <div style={rowStyle}>
      <Button buttonName="AC" clickHandler={clickHandler} color="#e0e0e0" />
      <Button buttonName="+/-" clickHandler={clickHandler} color="#e0e0e0" />
      <Button buttonName="%" clickHandler={clickHandler} color="#e0e0e0" />
      <Button buttonName="÷" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

And in the button:

```
const Button = props => {
  const { clickHandler, buttonName } = props;
  return <button onClick={() => clickHandler(buttonName)} type="button">{buttonName}</button>;
};
```

The thing is after console logs, the state is never changed, it's always returning NULL, as if it's not being processed. I have struggling with this for more than a day now.

Comment: Try returning `return { total, next, operation };` from the `calculate` function instead of `return data;`.

Comment: I'm saying that because you return `data` but you never mutate this object inside the function. If you do: `total = 10` it doesn't make `data.total` equal `10`.